# burned successfully but coastered dvd media

Tags: dvd

i am a newbie,
   I have just burned the dvd+rw with brasero, that completed without an error but after burning the dvd it is not mounting in any OS, let it be ubuntu or windows.
   here again if i replace the dvd then there is no problem but the one burned is really a problem.
   I have tried tool like dares and dares-qt but nothing is happening.

can any body help me how I can recover my dvd so that I can again use it???

Answer (score 0):

Simply reburn it, it is rewriteable.  A suggestion is never burn at maximum speed, especially when you have less 2 gigs of memory or are doing something else on the computer a the same time. The lower speed allows the  buffer to fill before writing to the DVD, permitting a constant flow of data.

Comment: thank u sir, but how can i burn when dvd is not mounting at all, i know the mount and tried but no difference it is not mounting at first